# Role Model Gem: How to get all Users with role: [:admin, :mentor]

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some search filters on my project. You can search Users by roles. If you search for `:admin` it will only return Users with role: `[:admin]`. But it WONT add the users to the search results with role: `[:admin, :mentor]`.

**Does anyone know how to make an SQL query that will find me all Users that have a role admin, they must include Users that have a role: [:admin, :mentor] as these users are still admin.**

```
    20:   custom_filter :role, lambda { |records, value|
 => 21:     binding.pry
    22:     records.where(roles_mask: User.mask_for(value))
    23:   }
    24:
    25:   class << self
    26:     def secure_find!(token:)

4.2.5.1@2.2.4 (User)> records
=> User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, roles_mask: integer)
4.2.5.1@2.2.4 (User)> value
=> "admin"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably passing only one role in `values`:

```
records.where(roles_mask: User.mask_for(value))
```

Make sure that `value` includes both:

```
records.where(roles_mask: User.mask_for([:admin, :mentor]))
```

Comment: Yeah it cant work like that. I need to see any users with a role [:admin]. What you have will just return users that have both roles `:admin`, and `:mentor`

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this

```
  custom_filter :role, lambda { |records, value|
    records.where("roles_mask & ? != 0", User.mask_for(value))
  }
```

This will return all `Users` that have a role `admin`. Even if the User has 2 roles or even 3 roles like `[:admin, :mentor]` it will inlcude his user in the result.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to select only users with a role [:admin], is to used **BINARY** operator.

Imagine your roles: `[:admin, :moderator, :writer]` in BINARY: `[1,2,4]`

In **MySQL/MariaDB**, select users with moderator roles:

```
select * from users where (BINARY(roles_mask) & BINARY(2)) > 0
```

In **Rails**:

```
User.where("(BINARY(roles_mask) & BINARY(#{User.mask_for([:moderator])})) > 0" )
```

or

```
User.where("(BINARY(roles_mask) & BINARY(?)) > 0", User.mask_for([:moderator]) )
```